# Switch from design/xaml window to code file in visual studio 11 for WPF Application

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

What is the shortcut to switch to code file in visual studio 11 from XAML file in WPF applications.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is working to switch from code to xaml/design mode, but couldn't find any shortcut for switching back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a bug. Now using Visual Studio 2012 RC and <kbd>F7</kbd> works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx#designerseditorsshared) it should be <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: VS11 is beta. Maybe that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little on the keyboard scheme you choose, however using the general settings, in the VS11 Beta <kbd>F7</kbd> takes you from the XAML designer to Code view, but there is no shortcut to go back the other way.

You need to go to Tools | Options | Keyboard and look for the View.ViewDesigner command.  Then set the "Use new shortcut in" dropdown to "Text Editor" and assign <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to the command. (Don't forget to press the assign button!)

Once done you should be able go from Code to Designer with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, and then back with <kbd>F7</kbd>.  If you want it the other way around, just change your keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Still not working. I guess its a flaw in VS11, as even the view code option in the context menu while in xaml file does not work.